# REACT NATIVE Retrieving data from localhost MySQL database

Tags: mysql, react-native, axios

I'm writing an app in React Native and I have created a MySQL database to store my information, but I was wondering if it was possible to use axios or fetch to interact with my database since it's local and doesn't have an HTTP address yet?
I feel like I used to be able to do it, but I forgot the syntax to use... If anyone knows anything, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Your local database has an IP address. It's 127.0.0.1, which is `localhost`. Either of those should work.

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct connection between React Native and Mysql. So you need to use Node js.

Step 1:

```
npm install express

npm install body-parser

npm install mysql
```

Step 2:

```
const connection = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'localhost', // Your connection adress (localhost).
  user     : 'root',     // Your database's username.
  password : '',        // Your database's password.
  database : 'my_db'   // Your database's name.
});

// Starting our app.
const app = express();

// Creating a GET route that returns data from the 'users' table.
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
    // Connecting to the database.
    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

    // Executing the MySQL query (select all data from the 'users' table).
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (error, results, fields) {
      // If some error occurs, we throw an error.
      if (error) throw error;

      // Getting the 'response' from the database and sending it to our route. This is were the data is.
      res.send(results)
    });
  });
});

// Starting our server.
app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log('Go to http://localhost:3000/users so you can see the data.');
});
```

To get the data in your React Native App. You need to use your PC's IP Address. If you use `localhost` you access the smartphone/emulator localhost. Here is an example to follow:

```
getData(){
fetch('http://yourpcip:3000/users')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(users => console.log(users))
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little confused... I have to make a nodejs app to interact with my database? Where should I put this code?

Comment: Node JS would be your backend. You would put that code inside of a `routes.js` file. React Native does not have a direct connection to MySQL. Check out this [Blog Post](https://dev.to/saulojoab/how-to-get-data-from-an-mysql-database-in-react-native-53a4)

Comment: You are right sorry, I used to do my backend in C# that's why I don't remember any of this... Thank you very much for your help!